# iBeacons Transmit and Receive UUID

Tags: ios, uuid, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm confused.

I created a Beacon using a CLBeaconRegion and advertising it with the CBPeripheralManager:

```
- (void)startTransmitting:(NSUUID*)uuid major:(NSInteger)major minor:(NSInteger)minor identifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                                major:major
                                                                minor:minor
                                                           identifier:identifier];

    self.beaconPeripheralData = [self.beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                     queue:nil
                                                                   options:nil];
}

-(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"Powered On");
        [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.beaconPeripheralData];
    } else if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"Powered Off");
        [self.peripheralManager stopAdvertising];
    }
}
```

And I was able to receive the iBeacon with the CBCentralManager:

```
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    [self.peripherals addObject:peripheral];
    NSLog(@"New Peripheral found and added... %@", peripheral);
}
```

This basically works. But the transmitted and the received UUID's are different - which in my opinion should be the same.

--> What did I do wrong / understand wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the UUID you read with `CBCentralManager` has nothing to do with the iBeacon's ProximityUUID.

Despite the use of the term UUID in both fields, they are completely different.  The field you can see with `CBCentralManager` is just a session-specific identifier generated by iOS.  If you use the same API to discover the same device at a later time, it will be a different value.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use `CoreBluetooth` APIs to read iBeacon identifiers.  For more information about why see [this blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).